# Compare 2 PHP files filled with variables, add missing variables from one to the other

Tags: php, performance

I've got 2 files (`settings1.php` and `settings1.default.php`) that contain settings variables for a website. When the site's files are updated, its pushed to Github so others can download and use the template site too. Obviously I don't want anyone to download my `settings1.php` file that contains MySQL database info and other personal info, and I don't want `settings1.php` to be wiped out when doing a `git pull`, so I have `settings1.default.php` that I update as I add new features.

An excerpt of the file is:

```
<?php
$apikey = "11111111111111";    
$TZ = "Europe/London";
$UTC = "1";
$lon = 0.2;
$lat = 50.1;
?>
```

My goal is to have a PHP script that (quickly) checks if each variable in `settings1.default.php` exists within `settings1.php`, and for each variable that doesn't exist, it copies that variable over including its default value. And if the entire `settings1.php` file is missing, it copies `settings1.default.php` to `settings1.php`. The script would need to contend with users adding blank lines between variables, or reordering the variables.

I've hacked out a script that, in a very messy way, does this, but only if there are no blank lines, and only if every variable is in the exact right order. Its a mess and probably very inefficient, so it'd be best to start over from scratch with the help of people that know PHP way better than I do.

Comment: show us your script.

Comment: Why not just load both files? `settings1.php` should just contain your local changes, they'll overwrite the variables that were set in the defaults file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others said use an array, but I would do it this way

```
//settings1.default.php
<?php
return [
    'apikey' => "11111111111111",
    'TZ' => "Europe/London";
    'UTC' => "1";
    'lon' => 0.2;
    'lat' => 50.1;
];
```

Then when you load them you can do it this way:

```
$default = require 'settings1.default.php';
$settings = require 'settings1.php';

//you could also use array_replace_recursive() but I would avoid array_merge_recursive()
$settings = array_merge($default, $settings);
```

And then if you want you can just use the merged arrays or, you can save that to a file like this:

```
file_put_contents('settings1.php', '<?php return '.var_export($settings, true).';');
```

Var Export returns a syntactically correct array, and the second argument returns it as a string rather then outputting it.  Then you just need to add the `<?php` tag, the `return` and the closing `;` to have PHP file.

This also keeps your variable space clean, if you add a variable, you have no grantee that someone using this does not already have that variable in use.  If they don't follow best practices in there code, there is the potential to overwrite data from one or both with unknown consequences. It would also be a bit hard to debug an issue like that.

**Your way**

It's possible to do what you want without doing this, but you will have to include the files in a function (so you have a clean scope), call `get_defined_vars` then merge the 2 arrays, then loop over that and manually create the PHP for the file.

If you don't use `get_defined_vars` in a "clean" scope you risk importing other variables into your settings files. This could lead to security issues as well.  What I mean by clean scope (just to be clear) is that within an empty function, the only variables that are defined are the ones used as arguments of the function (something we should all agree on).  So by doing this we can easily remove the only "non-setting" variable, which is the filename.  This way we can avoid a lot of those issues.  Without doing that you really have no way to know what all would be included in `get_defined_vars();`, or at least I don't have any idea what could leak into it.

```
  function loadSettings($file){
      require $file;
      unset($file); //remove file var you cant use this variable name in either file
      return get_defined_vars();
  }

  $default = loadSettings('settings1.default.php');
  $settings = loadSettings('settings1.php');

  //you could also use array_replace_recursive() but I would avoid array_merge_recursive()
  $settings = array_merge($default, $settings);

  $code = '<?php'."\n";

  foreach($settings AS $var => $value){
      /// ${var} = "{value}";\n
      $code .= '$'.$var.' = "'.$value.'"'.";\n"; //some issues with quotes on strings .. and typing here (no objects etc)
  }


  file_put_contents('settings1.php', $code);
```

Which just seems like a mess to me. Please note that you will have issues with the quotes on strings etc.. For example in the above code if the value of `$value` is `'some "string" here'`, this would create this line in the file `$foo = "some "string" here";` which is a syntax error. Var Export automatically escapes these things for you.  Not to mention what happens if you try to put an array in that value... Etc.  Frankly I am to lazy to try to work out all the edge cases for that.  Its what I like to call a naive implementation, because at first it looks easy but as you really get into it you have all these edge cases pop up.

Probably the only way to really fix that is to use `var_export` on each line like this:

```
      //...

foreach($settings AS $var => $value){
    /// ${var} = "{value}";\n
    $code .= '$'.$var.' = '.var_export($value,true).";\n";
}

      //...
```

You could try to do things like check if its an array, escape any non-escaped `"` some more type checking etc.  But whats the point as you may find other edge cases later etc..  Just a headache.  Var Export does a fantastic job of escaping the, and if you compare the two versions of the code, it should be clear why I made the original suggestion first.

One last note, is you can probably simplify the mixed quotes `'` and `"`.  I am just in a habit of doing everything that is PHP code in `'` because you can get into problems with this stuff.

```
//don't do this
$code .= "$$var = ".var_export($value,true).";\n";
//or this
$code .= "${$var} = ".var_export($value,true).";\n";
```

As PHP will think that is code and not a string.  Well it will see it as a variable variable, not something you want.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment

> Ended up using the second method you came up with. Also, figured out that if i replaced require with include inside the function, it would return an empty array, so the settings1.php file gets created with default values if it doesn't exist. Only thing I still need to work out is the easiest way to require settings1.default.php but not require settings1.php

I would make this small change:

```
  function loadSettings($file){

      if(!file_exists($file)) return []; //add this line

      require $file;
      unset($file); //remove file var you cant use this variable name in either file
      return get_defined_vars();
  }
```

While `include` has the behaviour you want, its not really the right thing to use here as you mentioned

> I still need to work out is the easiest way to require settings1.default.php but not require settings1.php

This breaks the commonality between them, which means we have to write more code with little or no benefit.  We can avoid that by adding a check in.  The only difference here is it makes using `require` vs `include` a bit pointless, **and both files would return an empty array** if they don't exist.  I would still use `require` because it means this code is important when you glance at it, rather or not it really does anything.

The part in bold above we can actually fix very easily by doing this:

```
  function loadSettings($file){

      if(basename($file) != 'settings1.default.php' && !file_exists($file)) return []; //add this line

      require $file;
      unset($file); //remove file var you cant use this variable name in either file
      return get_defined_vars();
  }
```

I left checking for the files orignally because I thought both file would always exist, and be required.  Adding the filename in there also adds a hard dependency on the setting file name.  If that file name changed you would have to change the code.  So i wanted to add it separate, as the other behaviour may be fine.

Base name gets the trailing part of the path to avoid issues with full paths to the file, this will return the filename.  Which makes matching it to our string of the filename a bit easier as we don't have to worry about the path.

So if the basename of the file is not equal to our *settings.default* file and the file does not exist return an array.  Then when the file is equal to that file it will bail out of the if condition and go to the require part rather or not the *settings.default* file exits.  Basically this will treat *settings.default* as a require, but still return an array on other files if they don't exist (like an include ).

Cheers!

Comment: Cool, this actually answers the OP's need to update the settings1.php file with the missing variables.

Comment: Yea one time I had a bunch of different dataset that all needed their own config file, I eventually got tired of adding them in, so I made a web based UI and used something like this to save them... :)

Comment: This is a template weather website that I'm heavily modifying, while also merging in updated features from upstream, so I can't radically change how the original guy stores and calls all the settings variables. I do like your first method, but the settings file is a bunch of variables, not a nice array. Is it possible to use your first method with the settings file containing variables and not an array?

Comment: No, because you can only return one thing in the way I showed `$default = require 'settings1.default.php';`, it's like a function call (in some ways) when you use `include` `require` etc.  and have a return in them.  Because we can't do that with multiple variables, then you have to get the defined variables etc... and we wind up at the second method pretty quickly.

Comment: I don't know your exact situation, but you could read one that way and not the other.  For example if one of the settings files is yours, and one is upstream.  You can read the upstream one with `get_defined_vars` and merge it with an array of your stuff and do the rest as I showed first.  Also you can use `export($settings)` to unwrap them (create variables from the array), one of the other answers showed this. That way if you need them as actual variables you can export the array... hope that makes sense. But as I said I don't know the full context.

Comment: Ended up using the second method you came up with. Also, figured out that if i replaced `require` with `include` inside the function, it would return an empty array, so the `settings1.php` file gets created with default values if it doesn't exist. Only thing I still need to work out is the easiest way to require `settings1.default.php` but not require `settings1.php`.

Comment: require them both, you code wont work without the files, include doesn't throw an error when the file is missing.  But you can check before doing it.

Comment: Works fantastically. I added some checks to make sure the folder is writable and if `settings1.default.php` doesn't exist, to download it from my github where the script will be stored, if you have a second, mind proof reading it to make sure I didn't miss anything? https://pastebin.com/JjJC5FWN

Comment: In your code, instead of unsetting the stuff in the github download you could do that as a function that you pass the file name to.  That way the variables are not in the `loadSettings` function, and you can re-use it to download other files from github.  Line `5 to 22` or so.  Other then that it looks pretty good.   So for example everywhere in that chunk you have `'./settings1.default.php'` could be `$filename` then you have another function `downloadFromGit($filename)` with that code in it.  Then of course where this stuff was you just put a call to that function.

Answer (score 1):

I would just store all of the variables in an array, then use `extract` to convert them to the actual variables, and use `array_intersect_key` to see if they length of the intersection of the arrays is the same as the length of `$defaultSettings`:

```
//settings1.default.php
$defaultSettings = [
    'apikey' => "11111111111111",
    'TZ' => "Europe/London";
    'UTC' => "1";
    'lon' => 0.2;
    'lat' => 50.1;
];

//settings.php
$settings = [
    'apikey' => "11111111111111",
    'TZ' => "Europe/London";
    'UTC' => "1";
    'lon' => 0.2;
    'lat' => 50.1;
];
extract($settings); // creates the variables $apikey, $TZ, etc.

//check.php
require('settings1.default.php')
require('settings.php')
//if they don't have the same keys
if (count(array_intersect_key($settings , $defaultSettings)) !== count($defaultSettings)) {
    throw new \Exception("Invalid configuration");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include settings1.default.php in settings1.php and then have to call get_defined_vars() which will have list of vars defined in settings1.default.php then if some variable does not exist in that array build additional config values in settings1.php.

settings1.php.

```
<?php

include_once('settings1.default.php');
$varialbes_defined_settings1_default = get_defined_vars();
```

?>

Comment: Yes, but there is no guarantee that all the vars came from the file, you would have to open it within the scope of a function, not procedural.